# aws s3 cp > how to implement the cp command with multipart copy in the aws Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

For the need of work, it would be handy to implement the 'aws s3 cp' command with aws Java SDK.

There are ready Class such as TransferManager, AmazonS3Client has get method. They can download the files to local file system easily, but the direct use of those method is only single thread. The given 'aws s3 cp' support the multipart copy anyway. Is there anyone who is familiar with this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

TransferManager is actually multi-threaded. You can pass it a thread pool to use. From [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html):

> When possible, TransferManager attempts to use multiple threads to
>   upload multiple parts of a single upload at once. When dealing with
>   large content sizes and high bandwidth, this can have a significant
>   increase on throughput.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great reply :) Actually this is my continuous question. I also noticed the constructor with the ExecutorService as a parameter. But my problem is I don't know how. Should I implement an ExecutorService by myself? or is there any thread pool for that? I feel that I have to implement the ExecutorService by myself

Comment: I'm pretty sure, based on the documentation for the constructors that don't take a thread pool as an argument, that it will just create a thread pool internally if you don't pass it one.